# Auto Updates on windows

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am trying to use the auto update feature, does anyone have a tutorial or something about how to do it? I've read the documentation but they only provide the available methods, not how to use them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

electron-builder – please use `nsis` target and use latest feature https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/529#issuecomment-253731088

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the best way to do electron auto-update is using electron-builder, use nsis.

> npm install electron-builer –save-dev
>
> npm install electron-updater –save

then follow this https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder

I couldn’t find any example for windows environment over internet and make this myself.

Please see [here](https://github.com/Longfld/electron-angular-material) for